# Hosting a Telethon User BOT on google-app-engine

Tags: google-app-engine-python, telethon

I am trying to deploy a simple user bot on Google App Engine Flexible Environment running python3.7, but I get the following error. Can anyone help me with suggestions of solving this?

"File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telethon/client/auth.py", line 20, in  phone: typing.Callable[[], str] = lambda: input('Please enter your phone (or bot token): '), EOFError: EOF when reading a line"

Thank you for your time

Comment: It looks like your client is prompting for input, which won't work when deployed to AppEngine. Can you provide the phone # or token in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now able to host my user BOT on GAE using the session string login method.

https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/sessions.html#string-sessions

Answer (score 0):

Telethon (obviously) requires you to login and make a normal user session on your account, which natively requires you to input your number when asked and enter the code received but since Google App engine doesn't allow input as @Sashidhar mentioned, depending on your userbot implementation, you can try using the userbot.session method for authentication, it can be generated locally and placed in the Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use python on app engine to call telethon functions, upon deploy the app. I receive the Internal Server Error from browser.

I am seeing you are success on this road, would you mind shine a light on this to help me starting up, such as how to configue the app.yaml, main.py,  requirements.txt , .... or any proper arrangement of librarys to make this work.

much much thanks in advance.

following is my main.py which raised server internal error on brows, the problem does not happen if this first telethon related line is remarked:

client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

```
main.py
--------
from flask import Flask, request
import datetime
import time
import asyncio

from telethon import  TelegramClient, events, sync

app = Flask(__name__)

api_id = xxxxxxxx
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
phone = '+xxxxxxxxxxxx'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    reqaction = request.args.get('action', 'connect')
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

would you mind shine a light on this to help me starting up, much thanks

Comment: ps: I have already use another connect.py excuted via GAE console (not a deployed app) to have successfully login tg, and the session file hence is stored and available for the above main.py  But I just cannot have deploy app call and use telehon functions such as TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)